# Get all site in webapp

Tags: rest, search-results, access

I'm trying to get all site collection where a user has access.
For this i use rest:

```
https://rootwebapp/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't get me all site where i have access. 
I tested with a farm admin who has access everywhere.

Are there an other way to get site or something i do wrong?

EDIT
If i make search 'contentclass:sts_site' in the searchbox from root webapp i see correctly the 150 site collections. With rest i see only 10
Thanks

Comment: That should do the trick. You are requesting Site Collections. If you want webs you can use sts_web.

Comment: I want all site collections not web. Unfortunately it doesn't return all site collection where i have access

Comment: It should. Are you crawling all of them?